# Pygame display only updates when I quit

Tags: python, pygame

Fiddling around with pygame and I'm not sure what's happening.
code is just supposed to make a red box and bounce it around a gray screen. It works, but only when I quit the display.

I've checked out questions that are similar but none seem to have an answer that applies to me (might be wrong about that). Does anyone know how this code could be improved?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from rect import *
##from pygame.font import *

RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAY = (150, 150, 150)

width = 500
height = 200

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

rect = Rect(100, 50, 50, 50)
v = [2, 2]

##moving = False
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
   
    rect.move_ip(v)

    if rect.left < 0 or rect.right > width:
        v[0] *= -1
    if rect.top < 0 or rect.bottom > height:
        v[1] *= -1

    screen.fill(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: By "not work", do you mean it jitters and moves very quickly? Because that's what I get when I run your code.

Comment: the black screen doesn't update to gray until i hit the quit button at which point the program does what I expected so far

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem is the program running too fast. Since so little work is being done in each loop, the rectangle ends up moving around too quickly to clearly see what is happening.

You can restrict the speed of the program using a `pygame.time.Clock` object. Before the start of your loop, probably right after your screen definition, you can construct a clock.

`clock = pygame.time.Clock()`

Then in your main loop, as the very first step each iteration (right after `while running:`) you can put `clock.tick(60)` to restrict the loop to running 60 times per second (60fps). This makes the program run smoothly, and you get the nice bouncing rectangle!

The `tick` method works well, but on my system it seems to have small hitches every so often. If you also experience this or if you want to be more accurate, you can use `clock.tick_busy_loop(60)` instead.

Both of these tick methods work the same way: By measuring the amount of time that passed since the last call to `clock.tick()` and delaying a certain additional amount based on that so that the target fps will be met.

More info on `Clock` at [Pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).

I also needed to `import pygame.rect` instead of just `import rect`, but if you're not getting an import error you should be fine.

Comment: no errors at all and I am able to see the square bouncing around, but i get a black screen up until i press the quit button, at which point the screen goes gray, the square appears and everything happens as it's supposed to. thank you though I'm going to tinker with this! EDIT: added ```clock.tick(60)``` and the square bounces around and a much nicer pace now, but still the same issue as before with the black screen

Comment: @StillLearnin Hmm, I am not having anything like that problem when I run your code. So the window comes up, is black, and turns gray when you press quit. How do you actually exit then? Do you have to press quit again? Are you sure you posted your full code? You can edit your question if needed.

Comment: that's too weird! yep, that's the full code and yes I have to press quit a second time in order to exit the window. thanks for the effort though!

Comment: @StillLearnin I see you're following this tutorial: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf#page35. Do the earlier examples work fine? Maybe you should a putting a `print("A")` and `print("B")` before and after the pygame.display.set_mode, to confirm that that is where it is getting stuck. Or maybe it is at pygame.init()?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing! I've gotten most earlier examples to work with a little tweaking and some help. I had some trouble on an earlier example where they were referencing things from later chapters. In the console it always prints                                       ```x=50, y=60, w=200, h=80
left=50, top=60, right=250, bottom=140
center=(150, 100)```                                                                          it seems you're right about it being stuck at pygame.init() because it will print what's above, but not "a" or "b" until i hit the quit button

Comment: @StillLearnin If it's printing something, it would appear that you still have some code from page 24. It then seems likely that you have either another `while running` loop, `pygame.init`, or another `pygame.display.set_mode`. If you run the code exactly as written in the question, with only the `clock` additions, it may work.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. Stupidly I had another file in my test directory named "rect.py", I changed the file name and my code to `from pygame.rect import *` and it's working fine now. Thank you Baked Potato for the help and for making me wonder where `x=50, y=60, w=200, h=80 left=50, top=60, right=250, bottom=140 center=(150, 100)` was coming from!